# iterate through a csv file using numpy

Tags: python, numpy, csv, iteration

I have a CSV file with 4 columns with x, y positions for tracks.
The 1st column is the ID of the track. The 2nd column is time. 3rd and 4th are X & Y co-ordinates.

Now the X & Y positions change with time (column#2) from 1 to 39. I have written functions (with for loops)that calculate Mean Square Displacement (MSD) for X and Y, as a function of time (column 2).

However, I want to create a 'for' loop in which the code can identify the ID# (from column 1), compute the above mentioned MSD for X & Y as function of time frame, for the first track. Then repeat this task for track#2 from column 1 and so on. Ultimately, write all of this data into a csv finally.

This would be a nested for loop where for every track# from col#1, it will compute MSD values.

Hope the problem statement is clear.

I am presenting data from ID#1 and ID#2 for simplification.

```
[ID Time    X   Y
1   0   1601.335544 496.4608855
1   1   1581.838184 497.3440951
1   2   1574.051153 493.2139985
1   3   1559.965258 504.9056873
1   4   1559.163646 493.4245832
1   5   1552.987661 494.2848072
1   6   1548.432535 497.3584389
1   7   1538.938784 495.0417267
1   8   1531.85109  489.0665788
1   9   1513.806745 504.7704007
1   10  1510.326674 497.5994863
1   11  1504.674908 506.2031946
1   12  1501.314024 509.9807796
1   13  1486.108431 530.8405735
1   14  1478.028873 528.9872163
1   15  1461.280431 555.1810352
1   16  1457.827357 544.1238295
1   17  1438.153357 546.1896118
1   18  1432.669134 536.079993
1   19  1421.693967 539.1976368
1   20  1420.047558 531.8360775
1   21  1407.484016 552.6212932
1   22  1401.323039 542.387526
1   23  1392.214888 550.167287
1   24  1383.369105 538.1534221
1   25  1376.908441 563.2408666
1   26  1375.965296 552.1877753
1   27  1356.164381 565.6603602
1   28  1350.494881 554.3032903
1   29  1343.425562 554.2145022
1   30  1338.147555 543.5654733
1   31  1319.226209 549.3667058
1   32  1315.186512 544.1423621
1   33  1304.524207 559.4354187
1   34  1307.192095 545.9207145
1   35  1297.79372  555.0278485
1   36  1293.623393 548.495482
1   37  1272.472404 556.9643619
1   38  1267.257919 553.4317279
1   39  1256.48484  564.7547876
2   0   1938.04852  502.2096272
2   1   1910.274979 499.4121209
2   2   1905.602566 494.564121
2   3   1892.023117 500.8674278
2   4   1890.41268  497.2568435
2   5   1889.370728 497.1678774
2   6   1879.222251 493.4259324
2   7   1854.213543 505.9090132
2   8   1849.009713 506.4718795
2   9   1827.907196 521.1249766
2   10  1825.557874 513.5055768
2   11  1811.655479 514.9185746
2   12  1804.375201 506.0495205
2   13  1790.033474 520.9751489
2   14  1782.406459 512.8187715
2   15  1768.6465   528.522878
2   16  1767.990804 526.0058206
2   17  1761.603106 535.8145984
2   18  1753.677501 517.6532347
2   19  1747.538543 539.0509296
2   20  1746.84304  531.1623969
2   21  1742.643159 543.8348459
2   22  1736.949154 534.7801535
2   23  1729.319064 542.8045771
2   24  1724.696825 533.3967561
2   25  1704.024318 549.7868714
2   26  1692.312454 544.4582317
2   27  1686.267143 547.7829218
2   28  1673.865039 545.091512
2   29  1662.986818 562.5577513
2   30  1656.270704 562.4002987
2   31  1642.961381 568.3286907
2   32  1643.388565 563.512262
2   33  1631.965059 570.7782627
2   34  1634.874901 563.7563826
2   35  1622.105795 574.0527937
2   36  1616.78351  569.5772635
2   37  1611.596229 576.4976228
2   38  1608.866078 567.6358896
2   39  1591.533636 576.2326799]
```

This is the for loop I use for computing MSD from X & Y.

```
def calc_msd_np(x):
    msd = []
    for s in range(1,len(x)):
        dx = x[s:] - x[:-s]
        msd.append(np.average(dx**2))
    return msd
print(calc_msd_np(x))
```

Similarly, I use the for loop for Y-coordinate. Basically, this MSD for X & Y needs to be iterated for each ID.

I am very new to this so figuring out nested loops is very challenging.

Comment: When I post the data it is well-segregated into columns. Moment i post it, its a mess. Any suggestions would be nice. Thanks!

Comment: Why not Pandas?

Comment: @kamleshbornani, StackOverflow formatting converts tabs to spaces in code blocks. You could properly align by spaces before copy-paste. Or just leave as is… I think we can figure it out. :)

Comment: If it's a CSV then paste the comma-separated values. That'll make things a little easier.

Comment: Please answer @jared's question about `pandas`, which would be very convenient here. Also, it looks like the results of `msd` are a list of the same length as the number of rows with a given ID. How do you want to store the results? Is it going to be another column of the table?

Comment: I can try Panda as I have never used it before. But the MSD formula needs to apply separately for ID#1 and ID#2 as they are two separate data points.

Comment: yes, the length of the output would be the same as the co-ordinates, as you compute MSD for each time difference and plots it as a function of time. Hence, the same length.

Comment: Use `groupby` and `transform/apply` from pandas

Comment: `grouping` is on area where pandas is more convenient than numpy.  numpy underlies pandas, but doesn't a convenient grouping mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

First convert your csv to pandas

```
df = pd.read_csv("yourcsv")
```

Secondly, define a new column named MSD and define a formula for MSD.

```
df["MSD"] = #MSD formula
```

Drop x and y columns to show only id, time and MSD columns.

```
new_df=df.drop(columns=["x","y"],axis=1)
```

Convert your pandas to csv.

```
new_df.to_csv("final.csv")
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But the MSD formula needs to apply separately for ID#1 and ID#2 as they are two separate data points. If i just isolate x & y for the whole CSV, that data would be incorrect. Hence, MSD needs to happen by the loop function for ID#1, then #2 ; separately. Therefore, maybe a nested one would help.

Comment: u can define  DF["MSD") inside loop as a output.